# Automated Enable of Wake on LAN

Tags: bios, wake-on-lan

Does anyone know of an automated way to enable Wake on LAN capabilities in the BIOS?

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if your motherboard manufacturer provides cmos/bios backup utilities (usually used just before upgrading the bios).  If so, you can likely get one machine set up the way you want it (including Wake-on-Lan), save those settings, and then restore them on other (identical) machines.

If your motherboard manufacturer doesn't provide such utils, perhaps [Flashrom](http://www.coreboot.org/Flashrom) will work.

Answer (score 1):

There is a linux tool called nvram-wakeup that allows you to programattically set the wakeup time of a box - but I think it also allows you to manipulate other bios settings.

smbios-utils is another utility worth looking at.

You could also check out the forums for MythTV, as that's where I first heard about this.  I know they deal with setting up wake-on-lan configurations - but I have not done that myself.